# regexp_replace in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I ran `regexp_replace` command on a Pyspark dataframe and after that the datatype of all data changed to String.Why is it so ?

Below is my table before using regex_replace

```
root
 |-- account_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- credit_card_limit: long (nullable = true)
 |-- credit_card_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phone_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shop: string (nullable = true)
 |-- transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
```

Schema after applying regexp_replace

```
root
 |-- date_type: date (nullable = true)
 |-- c_phone_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_account_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_credit_card_limit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_credit_card_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_amount: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_full_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_transaction_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c_shop: string (nullable = true)
```

The code I used:

```
df=df.withColumn('c_phone_number',regexp_replace("phone_number","[^0-9]","")).drop('phone_number')
df=df.withColumn('c_account_id',regexp_replace("account_id","[^0-9]","")).drop('account_id')
df=df.withColumn('c_credit_card_limit',regexp_replace("credit_card_limit","[^0-9]","")).drop('credit_card_limit')
df=df.withColumn('c_credit_card_number',regexp_replace("credit_card_number","[^0-9]","")).drop('credit_card_number')
df=df.withColumn('c_amount',regexp_replace("amount","[^0-9 ]","")).drop('amount')
df=df.withColumn('c_full_name',regexp_replace("full_name","[^a-zA-Z ]","")).drop('full_name')
df=df.withColumn('c_transaction_code',regexp_replace("transaction_code","[^a-zA-Z]","")).drop('transaction_code')
df=df.withColumn('c_shop',regexp_replace("shop","[^a-zA-Z ]","")).drop('shop')
```

Why is this happening ? Is there a way to convert this to its original datatype or should I use cast again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanted to look at the code from spark git for `regexp_replace`-

```scala
override def nullSafeEval(s: Any, p: Any, r: Any): Any = {
    if (!p.equals(lastRegex)) {
      // regex value changed
      lastRegex = p.asInstanceOf[UTF8String].clone()
      pattern = Pattern.compile(lastRegex.toString)
    }
    if (!r.equals(lastReplacementInUTF8)) {
      // replacement string changed
      lastReplacementInUTF8 = r.asInstanceOf[UTF8String].clone()
      lastReplacement = lastReplacementInUTF8.toString
    }
    val m = pattern.matcher(s.toString())
    result.delete(0, result.length())

    while (m.find) {
      m.appendReplacement(result, lastReplacement)
    }
    m.appendTail(result)

    UTF8String.fromString(result.toString)
  }
```

1. the above code accepts the expression as `Any` and then call `toString()` on it
2. At last, it is converting the result again in `toString`

```scala
UTF8String.fromString(result.toString)
```

ref - [spark-git](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/regexpExpressions.scala#L340)